Odoo 17 - Show new field in POS receipt
I'm using Odoo 17 pos I've added new field called is_void, I want to access this field from the receipt, It comes with undefined (empty), but It sent to the DB Correctly here is my code below:
Python:
from odoo import models, fields


class PosOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.order.line"

    is_void = fields.Boolean(
        string="Is Void",
        default=False,
        help="Indicates whether this line is voided or not.",
    )

    def _order_line_fields(self, line, session_id=None):
        result = super(PosOrderLine, self)._order_line_fields(line, session_id)
        result["is_void"] = line.get("is_void", False)
        return result

    def _export_for_ui(self, orderline):
        result = super()._export_for_ui(orderline)
        result.update(
            {
                "is_void": orderline.is_void,
            }
        )
        return result

Javascript:
patch(Orderline.prototype, {
  constructor() {
    this.is_void = this.is_void || false;
  },

  // // Toggle the is_void flag
  toggleVoid() {
    this.is_void = !this.is_void;
  },

  // Include is_void in export_as_JSON
  export_as_JSON() {
    const result = super.export_as_JSON(...arguments);
    result["is_void"] = this.is_void;
    return result;
  },

  init_from_JSON(json) {
    super.init_from_JSON(...arguments);
    this.is_void = json.is_void || false;
  },

  export_for_printing() {
    const json = this._super(...arguments);
    json.is_void = this.is_void;
    return json;
  },
});

Getting the below error

point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:9701 Failed to send orders: [{…}]
_save_to_server @ point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:9701
RPC_ERROR://localhost:8069/web/assets/7b7dc0e/point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:6586:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/7b7dc0e/point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:6590:13)

Also I tried to load_params but this solution works only if the custom field is predefined not defined or set its value during making the order itself.
